How to make entry fields and buttons transparent while using a background image in Tkinter?
I'm working on a Tkinter project where I have a login screen with a background image. I want to make the entry fields for "Username" and "Password" transparent, so the background image is visible behind them. Additionally, I would like to make the "Login" and "Register" buttons have a transparent background as well, but without affecting their functionality.
I tried using the bg="transparent" option for the entry fields and buttons, but I got an error, since Tkinter does not support transparent backgrounds directly.
enter image description here
Here's code snippet of my current setup:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # Pillow modülünü içeri aktar


def setup_database():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("todo_app.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        username TEXT NOT NULL,
        password TEXT NOT NULL
    )
    """)
    cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        user_id INTEGER,
        task TEXT NOT NULL,
        completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
    )
    """)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def login_screen():
    def login():
        username = username_entry.get()
        password = password_entry.get()
        conn = sqlite3.connect("todo_app.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (username, password))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        conn.close()

        if user:
            messagebox.showinfo("Başarılı", "Hoşgeldiniz Lordum!")
            main_screen(user[0])  # Kullanıcı ID'sini ana ekrana gönder
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Hata", "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış!")

    def register():
        username = username_entry.get()
        password = password_entry.get()
        if username and password:
            conn = sqlite3.connect("todo_app.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (username, password))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            messagebox.showinfo("Başarılı", "Kayıt başarılı! Giriş yapabilirsiniz.")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Hata", "Kullanıcı adı ve şifre boş olamaz!")

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Giriş Yap")


    width, height = 200, 200  
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width - width) // 2
    y = (screen_height - height) // 2
    root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}")  


    background_image = Image.open("loginbackground.png")  # Resmi yükle
    background_image = background_image.resize((width, height))  
    background_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)  

    background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_photo)  
    background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)  
    
    login_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='white')  
    login_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")  

    tk.Label(login_frame, text="Kullanıcı Adı:", fg="black", bg="white").pack(pady=5)
    username_entry = tk.Entry(login_frame, bd=0, relief="flat", highlightthickness=0)  # Borderless entry
    username_entry.pack(pady=5)

    tk.Label(login_frame, text="Şifre:", fg="black", bg="white").pack(pady=5)
    password_entry = tk.Entry(login_frame, show="*", bd=0, relief="flat", highlightthickness=0)  # Borderless entry
    password_entry.pack(pady=5)


    tk.Button(login_frame, text="Giriş Yap", command=login, bd=0, relief="flat", bg="#d3d3d3").pack(pady=5)
    tk.Button(login_frame, text="Kayıt Ol", command=register, bd=0, relief="flat", bg="#d3d3d3").pack(pady=5)

    root.mainloop()


def main_screen(user_id):
    def add_task():
        task = task_entry.get()
        if task:
            conn = sqlite3.connect("todo_app.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tasks (user_id, task) VALUES (?, ?)", (user_id, task))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            task_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            load_tasks()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Hata", "Görev boş olamaz!")

    def delete_task(task_id):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("todo_app.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = ?", (task_id,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        load_tasks()

    def load_tasks():
        for widget in task_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        
        conn = sqlite3.connect("todo_app.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT id, task FROM tasks WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
        tasks = cursor.fetchall()
        conn.close()

        for task_id, task in tasks:
            frame = tk.Frame(task_frame)
            frame.pack(fill="x", pady=2)

            tk.Label(frame, text=task).pack(side="left", padx=5)
            tk.Button(frame, text="Sil", command=lambda tid=task_id: delete_task(tid)).pack(side="right")

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Yapılacaklar Listesi")


    width, height = 800, 600  
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width - width) // 2
    y = (screen_height - height) // 2
    root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}")

    task_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    task_entry.pack(pady=5)

    tk.Button(root, text="Ekle", command=add_task).pack(pady=5)

    task_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    task_frame.pack(pady=10)

    load_tasks()
    root.mainloop()

# Programı başlat
if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_database()
    login_screen()


What I tried: I have tried using the bg="transparent" option for the Entry and Button widgets in Tkinter, hoping to make them transparent. I also removed borders and set their relief property to flat. Additionally, I used the Pillow library to add a background image to the Tkinter window. I have also attempted to remove the default background color of these widgets and experimented with setting different properties like bd=0 and highlightthickness=0.
What I expected: I was expecting the entry fields for the "Username" and "Password" to be transparent so that the background image is visible behind them. Similarly, I expected the "Login" and "Register" buttons to have a transparent background so that the window's background image would show through these UI elements as well.
However, even after applying these changes, I still see a white background behind the entry fields and buttons, which is not the behavior I was expecting.

As you already said in your question, tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.  However, you can try this.

Consider using canvas.

Using Python 3.12.7, Windows 10

How to make entry fields and buttons transparent while using a
background image in Tkinter?

Edit: You cannot get Entrys and Buttons widget transparent. Only Label widget you can see it. If you clicked it, it will disappear.
I do not use sqlite3.
The problem can be fixed.

Do not use this wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', '#ab23ff').  It will disappear.
Use one root = tk.Tk() and root.mainloop() for entire script.
For open new window. you use root = tk.Toplevel(). No need to add
maniloop().
Add root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.8) inside login_screen()
function. You can use 0.5 to suit your need.
Comment out login_frame. It is up to you.
Replace login_frame with root for tkinter widgets.
You may change background bg='#ab23ff' color to suit your need.

Snippet:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # Pillow modülünü içeri aktar


 

def login_screen():
    def login():
        username = username_entry.get()
        password = password_entry.get()
         

        if user:
            messagebox.showinfo("Başarılı", "Hoşgeldiniz Lordum!")
            main_screen(user[0])  # Kullanıcı ID'sini ana ekrana gönder
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Hata", "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış!")

    def register():
        username = username_entry.get()
        password = password_entry.get()
        
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Giriş Yap")
    root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.5)
     


    width, height = 200, 200  
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width - width) // 2
    y = (screen_height - height) // 2
    root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}")  


    background_image = Image.open("p2.png")  # Resmi yükle
    background_image = background_image.resize((width, height))  
    background_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)  

    background_label = tk.Label(root, bg='#ab23ff', image=background_photo)  
    background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)  
    
    #login_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#ab23ff',)  
    #login_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")  

    tk.Label(root, text="Kullanıcı Adı:", fg="black", bg='#ab23ff',).pack(pady=5)
    username_entry = tk.Entry(root, bd=0, fg='white', bg='#ab23ff', relief="flat", highlightthickness=0)  # Borderless entry
    username_entry.pack(pady=5)

    tk.Label(root, text="Şifre:", fg="black", bg="white").pack(pady=5)
    password_entry = tk.Entry(root, show="*", fg='white', bg='#ab23ff', bd=0, relief="flat", highlightthickness=0)  # Borderless entry
    password_entry.pack(pady=15)


    tk.Button(root, text="Giriş Yap", command=login, bg='#ab23ff', bd=0, relief="flat"  ).pack(pady=5)
    tk.Button(root, text="Kayıt Ol", command=register, bg='#ab23ff', bd=0, relief="flat" ).pack(pady=5)

    root.mainloop()


def main_screen(user_id):
    ....
    ....
    
    root = tk.Toplevel()
    root.title("Yapılacaklar Listesi")

    ....
    ....


    

# Programı başlat
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #setup_database() 
    login_screen()

Screenshot:

Edit: To use Frame widget This is what is look like.
Screenshot for Frame:

